# "the game of Go" vs. "Go game"

Tags: word-usage

[Go is an abstract strategy board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) for two players, in which the aim is to surround more territory than the opponent. The game was invented in China more than 2,500 years ago and is believed to be the oldest board game continuously played to the present day.

A classmate and I were practicing speaking

> He: "I like traveling, cooking and watching movies."
>
> I: "I like watching movies too and I also like playing Go."
>
> He: "what go?"
>
> I: "**The game of Go**, a Chinese board game"

Should I have said "Go game" there, are there any other expression more natural or easier to hear I could use in this context?

Comment: **Go**, or to be clearer, **the game of Go**.

Comment: I'm a go player, I've watched a lot of go teaching materials and people generally say "go" or "the game of go". I'd've said just "Go, a Chinese board game", but I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the "game of Go" and "Go game" are legitimate.  However, given the potential of confusion (especially since Go means something else as an English word), "game of Go" is probably clearer to the ordinary listener.